# Exchange 2010 add mailbox server to DAG error

Tags: exchange-2010

i'm having some problems when adding a second mailbox server to my DAG in Exchange 2010.
The test setup goes like this: 1x windows server 2008 (DC/DNS)
                               2x windows server 2008 (Exchange 2010)

I have made sure all services are up and running and that the "Exchange Trusted Subsystem" account is set as a local admin.

When i create a DAG i can add the first mailbox server (A) without any problems, but when i go to add the second (B) it gives me an error saying "Unable to contact the Cluster service on 1 other members (member) of the Database availability group.

It does the same if i add (B) first and then try to add (A).

Here is a part of the log file:

[2010-04-05T15:00:27] GetRemoteCluster() for the mailbox server failed with exception = An Active Manager operation failed. Error: An error occurred while attempting a cluster operation. Error: Cluster API '"OpenCluster(EXCHANGE20102.area51.com) failed with 0x6d9. Error: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper"' failed.. This is OK.

[2010-04-05T15:00:27] Ignoring previous error, as it is acceptable if the cluster does not exist yet.
[2010-04-05T15:00:27] DumpClusterTopology: Opening remote cluster AREA51DAG01.
[2010-04-05T15:00:27] DumpClusterTopology: Failed opening with Microsoft.Exchange.Cluster.Replay.AmClusterApiException: An Active Manager operation failed. Error: An error occurred while attempting a cluster operation. Error: Cluster API '"OpenCluster(AREA51DAG01.area51.com) failed with 0x5. Error: Access is denied"' failed. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: only optiong was to re-install everything and sysprep the Vms. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from original author [Michael](https://serverfault.com/users/39725/michael):

only option was to re-install everything and sysprep the Vms. That worked.